# PowerShell filter in utf8 output from MSMQ journal

Tags: powershell

I have this code:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Messaging")

$queueName = '.\Private$\wwprodmsgqueue1.0\Journal$';
$queue = new-object System.Messaging.MessageQueue $queueName;
$utf8 = new-object System.Text.UTF8Encoding;

$msgs = $queue.GetAllMessages();
$msgs | %{
    write-host $_.Id;
    write-host $utf8.GetString($_.BodyStream.ToArray())
```

And I want to filter so I only get Journal for this name "A15C05U01_SAPProduced"

```
  <MessageID>acc8bc3f-b0b7-4362-8c93-b80cf69c78f4</MessageID>
  <MessageName>Produce Material</MessageName>
  <Retry>false</Retry>
  <MessageData>
    <string>A15C05U01_SAPProduced</string>
    <string>A15C05U01_ProdLog.Produce.LogProduced</string>
    <string>A15C05U01</string>
    <string>BSM_Förpackning.A15.Pallastare_5</string>
  </MessageData>
```

Have tried with "| Where-Object {$utf8.MessageName -like "Produce Material"}"

Comment: Please show us more of the xml you have (you can shorten it, but keep the structure so we have valid xml to work with). Also, what output do you want? Please [edit] the question and put that in.

Comment: The `BodyStream` property is a `Stream` object and you cannot pass it to `UTF.GetString()`. That method requires a `byte[]`. You have to manually convert the stream to a byte array. Afterwards you can convert that to a string.